# Download and use SQLite Database on React-Native Application

Tags: database, sqlite, encryption, react-native

i need to open prepopulated, encrypted database using `react-native-sqlite-storage` (modified by dryganet: https://github.com/dryganets/react-native-sqlite-storage/tree/sergeyd/sqlite-cipher), this prepopulated datatabase is downloaded from remote location using `react-native-fs`.

At this moment when i put database in assets folder (this database is copied during `react-native run-android` command) and fire method "openDatabase":

```
const dbName = "myDatabase.db";
const dbLocation = "~database.db";
const encryptionLey = "asdfghasdfgh";

const queryDatabase = async (tx) => {
  const [sqliteTx, results] = await tx.executeSql(sqlQuery);
  resultData = results;
};

const db = await SQLite.openDatabase({ 
    name: dbName,
    createFromLocation: dbLocation, 
    key: encryptionKey
 }, (result) => {...}, (result) => {...});

await db.transaction(queryDatabase);

retrun resultData;
```

everything works correctly, but i need to download this database during runtime, so... when i change dbLocation to:

```
const dbLocation = fs.DocumentDirectoryPath + "/database.db";
```

and download sqlite database from remote location:

```
fs.downloadFile({,
      fromUrl: "http://10.0.2.2:63074/Database/GetDatabase",
      toFile: dbLocation,
    }).promise.then(res => {
      fs.exists(dbLocation).then(fileExist => {
        ...
      });
    });
```

Everything stops working, no errors occures, in debug console i can see this:

```
OPEN database: myDatabase.db
new transaction is waiting for open operation
```

Where is the problem? I uses SQLCipher to encrypt and decrypt database.
Maybe there is another way to achieve this, the solution must works both on Android and iOS?

Comment: did you find a solution in ReactNative?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i found solution by myself, in Native Java code, there is place like:

```
        if (assetFilePath != null && assetFilePath.length() > 0) {
            if (assetFilePath.compareTo("1") == 0) {
                assetFilePath = "www/" + dbname;
                in = this.getContext().getAssets().open(assetFilePath);
                FLog.v(TAG, "Located pre-populated DB asset in app bundle www subdirectory: " + assetFilePath);
            } else if (assetFilePath.charAt(0) == '~') {
                assetFilePath = assetFilePath.startsWith("~/") ? assetFilePath.substring(2) : assetFilePath.substring(1);
                in = this.getContext().getAssets().open(assetFilePath);
                FLog.v(TAG, "Located pre-populated DB asset in app bundle subdirectory: " + assetFilePath);
            } else {
                File filesDir = this.getContext().getFilesDir();
                assetFilePath = assetFilePath.startsWith("/") ? assetFilePath.substring(1) : assetFilePath;
                File assetFile = new File(filesDir, assetFilePath);
                in = new FileInputStream(assetFile);
                FLog.v(TAG, "Located pre-populated DB asset in Files subdirectory: " + assetFile.getCanonicalPath());
                if (openFlags == SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY) {
                    dbfile = assetFile;
                    FLog.v(TAG, "Detected read-only mode request for external asset.");
                }
            }
        }
```

That means i need to set `createFromLocation:"database.db"` in this case, because rest of the path will be added automaticaly in java native code.